# How to show a different page in a lightBox(Primefaces), then when this page submitted back to the first page?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to show a different page in a dialog/lightBox(Primefaces) and after that page submitted return back to the first page.

```
<h:link onclick="createUserDialog.show();" value="Create New User">
    <p:dialog widgetVar="createUserDialog" modal="true">
        <h:outputLink value="createUser.jsf" >
        <ui:include src="createUser.xhtml"></ui:include>
        </h:outputLink>
    </p:dialog>
</h:link>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<p:commandLink onclick="createUserDialog.show();" value="Create New User" />
<p:dialog widgetVar="createUserDialog" modal="true">
    <ui:include src="createUser.xhtml" />
</p:dialog>
```

And in createUser.xhtml:

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        ...
        <p:commandButton value="button" oncomplete="createUserDialog.hide();" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```